# AnyLogic: Draw values from a Custom Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, anylogic

I created a CustomDistribution programmatically via the constructor

CustomDistribution distribution = new CustomDistribution(double[]interval_starts, double[]probabilities)

How can I then draw random values from this distribution? Do I have to define a random number generator? Or can I simply draw random values via `distribution.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:
`distribution()`